# Initramfs: ERROR: Bad version passed vmlinuz-5.15.36

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I trying to build the kernel 5.15.36. My standard kernel - 5.17.5. During initramfs I get error:
Bad version passed vmlinuz-5.15.36

What to do?

Comment: Are OS/release are you using?  You've tagged 22.04, but mention your standard kernel is 5.17 which is not the LTS kernel used by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I myself updated the kernel in the program "Mainline Kernel Updater".

Comment: Oh, program Ukuu